# iPad and Wifi Access point on a MAC restricted network

Tags: network-monitoring, mac-address, ipad

I'm trying to help my sister get her iPad online in her university halls of residence. She has one ethernet port in her room and there is no wireless provided.

I got her a wireless router (which is set up to not broadcast SSID and get an IP address via DHCP) which is connected to the wall socket to the WAN port of the router. We tested this set up at our parents house after christmas and it all worked.

She is now back at Uni (and myself back home so we are 500 miles apart) and things aren't going according to plan. She asked around and found out that she needed to provide the MAC address of the device connecting to the network. I told her to provide the MAC address of the wireless adapter but this is not working.

A friend down the corridor was able to get online with their laptop using my system ethernet socket.

Should I tell her to provide the network administrator with the MAC address of her iPad instead?

I would be really appreciative if someone could explain a little about how MAC address blocked works in this kind of set up from a network admins point of view?

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on SuperUser, not ServerFault, but here goes...

Set the WiFi router up in NAT mode. Give the MAC address of the WiFi router to the University - it is the device that campus "sees". The iPad and any other things hooked up to the router via WiFi are "hidden" behind the NAT that the router is doing. Be VERY sure you ALWAYS plug the WAN socket on the router into the wall - otherwise your campus IT people will become very upset with you.

The MAC address in question needs to be the WAN interface MAC, which you can get from the router - which isn't necessarily the same as the WiFi interface MAC address. It may take some time for campus to update itself with the new MAC address.